# unreadable characters using codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I work on a C project and continue another group's work, there are unreadable characters using codeblocks  when I opened the source file. For example:

```
printf("ÎÄ¼þ´ò¿ªÊ§°Ü!") ;
```

I changed the setting of the editor and make the encoding utf-8 but still the same.

Comment: please! elaborate your question.

Comment: The editor uses the default character encoding of your host operating system. This setting will be displayed with default.It looks like  there is mismatch between project encoding and your editor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using the appropriate encoding. You can check the charset in a linux shell, using command "file":

```
file -bi [filename]
```

Comment: Or, you could just ask the "other team" which encoding they use, and why that is not properly documented.